# Send additional data with dropzone to the backend

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, dropzone.js

I am trying to send through dropzone a specific -already known- position ID of an image file to the backend, which is going to be uploaded on the server.
Although the `formData.append()` is being used, I see that nothing is appended.Instead just this "`FormData {}`" shows up.

```
dropzoneObject.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData){
    var nameOfFile = $(file.previewElement).find(".dz-filename").text();
    var positionOfFile = fpos;
    //console.log("The file who's being sent is named: "+nameOfFile+" and its position id is: "+positionOfFile);
    formData.append("fpos", fpos);
});
```

I expect to see in example fpos=16;

Comment: I don't see any problem, it should appear in server side, per example in php should appear inside `$_POST`.

Comment: Same goes for me, but I look at what it's sent to the backend, and it's this:

------WebKitFormBoundaryQ1oUGxyQMqHxtZLB
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="motiv[14]"; filename="sPYaY6Tb_w.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg.

Although there is data-form to be sent, it's not :/ I really really need to find a way to push the position ID to the back end. @wallek876

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't know about your particular error, but here is a simple example of how to send additional data with dropzone using jQuery and receiving it with php on the backend.

html:

```
<form id="myForm" class="dropzone"></form>
```

js:

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
$('.dropzone').dropzone ({
        url: "upload.php",
        init: function() {
            this.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData){
                formData.append("fpos", 777)
            }),
            this.on("success", function(file, xhr){
                alert(file.xhr.response);
            })
        },
});
```

The success event is only to demonstrate how to access the response send from the server:

php:

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') 
    {
        echo "RECEIVED ON SERVER: \n";
        echo "FILES: \n";
        print_r($_FILES);
        echo "\$_POST: \n";
        print_r($_POST);
    }
```

The php simply sends back to client the same data received, just to show where is accessible.

Comment: Thank you very much. Apparently, the data-form was always sending info but it wouldn't show up on post request. It didn't occur to me to check if the back-end receives it at all, as I thought it wouldn't be there since I didn't see it.
You are a lifesaver.

Comment: This will keep appending the value to same key again and again if uploadMultiple flag is enabled.

Comment: @SumitJoshi I don't think so, If `uploadMultiple` is enabled dropzone sends the files in the queue in one request along with the form data. That said, if the number of files in the queue is greater than the limit of files specified by the option `parallelUploads` dropzone will send the files in batches containing at most the number files specified in `parallelUploads`, as example if there are 5 files in the queue and `parallelUploads` is 2, dropzone will send the files in 3 requests, each request containing the same form data, so you will send the same form data 3 times.