# How to add input box to Dropzone.js and sent the value to another API endpoint?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

Currently I'm using the bootstrap theme config of dropzone.js, e.g. http://www.dropzonejs.com/bootstrap.html. What I want to achieve here is, add one input box to let the user input custom pic title, and another td in the table to show the response info(e.g. full link to the uploaded pic). After uploading done, send the pic title and pic link to another API endpoint to save them.

Tried to work with listening on `addedFile` and `success` but with no luck...The preview template is almost the same as in the docs. Really not skillful in HTML and Javascript. :(

```
<div class="table table-striped files" id="previews">
  <div id="template" class="file-row">
    <!-- This is used as the file preview template -->
    <div>
        <span class="preview"><img data-dz-thumbnail /></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p class="name" data-dz-name></p>
        <strong class="error text-danger" data-dz-errormessage></strong>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p class="title">
        <input type="text" name="title" id="title" placeholder="Input pic title or comment here!">
      </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <!-- URL returned should be here? -->
        <p id="fpurl" class="error text-danger"></p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p class="size" data-dz-size></p>
        <div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0">
          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;" data-dz-uploadprogress></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="btn btn-primary start">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
          <span>Start</span>
      </button>
      <button data-dz-remove class="btn btn-warning cancel">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
          <span>Cancel</span>
      </button>
      <button data-dz-remove class="btn btn-danger delete">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
        <span>Delete</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

JS code below:

```
  var previewNode = document.querySelector("#template");
  previewNode.id = "";
  var previewTemplate = previewNode.parentNode.innerHTML;
  previewNode.parentNode.removeChild(previewNode);

  var myDropzone = new Dropzone(document.body, {
    url: "http://upload/file/url",
    paramName: "fpfile",
    thumbnailWidth: 80,
    thumbnailHeight: 80,
    headers: {"Cache-Control": null},
    parallelUploads: 20,
    previewTemplate: previewTemplate,
    autoQueue: false, // Make sure the files aren't queued until manually added
    previewsContainer: "#previews", // Define the container to display the previews
  });

  myDropzone.on("addedfile", function(file) {
    // Hookup the start button
    file.previewElement.querySelector(".start").onclick = function() { myDropzone.enqueueFile(file); };
  });

  // Update the total progress bar
  myDropzone.on("totaluploadprogress", function(progress) {
    document.querySelector("#total-progress .progress-bar").style.width = progress + "%";
  });
  myDropzone.on("success", function(file, response) {
    var j = $.parseJSON(response);
    var responseurl = $.parseJSON(j).url;
    var fname = file.name;

    // alert(file.name);
  });

 myDropzone.on("sending", function(file, xhr, data) {
  // Auth info
  data.append("Authorization", "Secret code here");
  // Show the total progress bar when upload starts
  document.querySelector("#total-progress").style.opacity = "1";
  // And disable the start button
  file.previewElement.querySelector(".start").setAttribute("disabled",   "disabled");
});

  // Hide the total progress bar when nothing's uploading anymore
  myDropzone.on("queuecomplete", function(progress) {
    document.querySelector("#total-progress").style.opacity = "0";
  });

  // Setup the buttons for all transfers
  // The "add files" button doesn't need to be setup because the config
  // `clickable` has already been specified.
  document.querySelector("#actions .start").onclick = function() {
    myDropzone.enqueueFiles(myDropzone.getFilesWithStatus(Dropzone.ADDED));
  };
  document.querySelector("#actions .cancel").onclick = function() {
    myDropzone.removeAllFiles(true);
  };
```

Comment: I think this other question should help you, is very similar. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32778840/send-additional-data-with-dropzone-to-the-backend/32822996#32822996

Comment: @wallek876 Thx! I'll dig it tonight and see if I can make it work.