# How to send params value calculated at runtime in Dropzone.js

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dropzone.js

I have a pretty basic Dropzone in an asp.net core app:

```
                       <div class="panel-body " id="dropzone">
                            <form asp-action="Upload" class="dropzone 
                                 needsclick dz-clickable" id="uploader">
                                <div class="dz-message needsclick">
                                    Drop files here or <a class="btn btn- 
                                           primary">click</a> to upload.<br>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
```

I'm trying to set up a params value in the config, because in some situations there is a selectlist where the user chooses a value that must be passed to the MVC controller. The param is always null and I have a feeling it's because of the way I am setting the configuration:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        Dropzone.options.uploader = {
            acceptedFiles: ".csv, .xls, .xlsx",
            init: function () {
                this.on("error", function (file) {
                    if (!file.accepted) alert("csv, xls, and xlsx files only. File not uploaded");
                    this.removeFile(file);
                });
            },
            params: { orgId: $('#orglist').val()}
        };
```

I'm guessing my params value is calculated at doc ready and never again. How I can I pass the value currently selected when the actual file is dragged?

Comment: That's right, the values in the options are only used when dropzone is first initialized. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32778840/send-additional-data-with-dropzone-to-the-backend

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send additional data with dropzone to the backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32778840/send-additional-data-with-dropzone-to-the-backend)

Answer (score 0):

The answer I found was to add a listener to the send function and remove params option, and append a new parameter orgID which is a parameter in my controller action :

```
Dropzone.options.uploader = {
            acceptedFiles: ".csv, .xls, .xlsx",
            init: function () {
                this.on("error", function (file) {
                    if (!file.accepted) alert("csv, xls, and xlsx files only. File not uploaded");
                    this.removeFile(file);
                });
                this.on("sending", function (file, xhr, formData) {
                    formData.append("orgId", $('#orglist').val())
                })
            }
```